# java.sql.Connection tests against a PostgreSQL 8.4.6

Tags: java, database, performance, postgresql, database-connection

I have a postgresql DB with > 3 million rows in two tables.
Something slows down the whole performance, so I analyzed a bit with the Ubuntu command `pg_top`.

I found out there is always a query like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM <tablename>;
```

Looks like a connection test statement from the `java.sql.Connection`, right?

When I enter the same command in the postgres command, it takes **4 seconds**! Indexes are all there, I checked that.

**Question:**
How can I change the test statement used by the Connection object?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you directly connecting per JDBC to the database or over Hibernate (or similar?)

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? Details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root Cause has been found:
A framework my code was relying on did test whether the table is available or not.
This was done via

```
SELECT 1 from TABLENAME;
```

This actually returns ALL ROWS from that table and because I have 3 million rows in it, it takes a while.

A much better approach (at least for POSTGRESQL) is this one:

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'mytable';
```

**Thanks for all for the already posted comments!**

See [source of the solution](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/pg_class) .

Comment: Of course `select 1 from tablename` will return all rows because there is no WHERE clause. Why would you expect it to return less rows? Btw: a somewhat portable SQL would be `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'mytable'`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using some kind of connection pool, directly or indirectly over a datasource or some other framework like hibernate.

Check in the documentation of the connection pool and search for the term 'validation query'.
For postgres you should be able to set a query like:

```
select version();
```

This should be much faster.

Comment: I agree. The "Connection" object does not do any validation at all. Btw: a simple `SELECT 1` might even be (slightly) faster